# How to render file's download button only if the file is available using primefaces 5.3

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Java EE 7 -- Primefaces 5.3 
I am uploading a list of files then I return another page that provides access to the users to download these files. When the user hits the download button, I pass the fileName back to my controller as an attribute then return the file to download. I am looking for a way to render the download button if the file is available. is that possible? If so how?

Here is files datatable in the download.xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable var="file" value="#{controller.fileList}">
   <p:column headerText="File Name">
       <p:outputLabel value="#{file.fileName}"/>
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="download">
        <p:commandButton value="Download"    id="download" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" ajax="false" actionListener="#{controller.prepareToDownload}" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
                <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{file.fileName}" />
                <p:fileDownload value="#{controller.download}" />
        </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
```

Controller:

```
 public void prepareToDownload(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String directory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("uploadDirectory");
        fileName = (String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fileName");
        file = new File(directory, fileName);
              InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        download = new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName());
    }

public void setDownload(DefaultStreamedContent download) {
        this.download = download;
    }

    public DefaultStreamedContent getDownload() throws Exception {
        return download;
    }
```

Comment: By using the rendered attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. controller.fileList() provides the files ready for download => no chances for downloading a non-existing file
2. controller.fileList() provides a list of files, including files not ready for download => use the rendered or disabled attribute of the commandButton